# CallKit/Voip: how does a caller handle become blocked?

Tags: ios, callkit

In the iOS 13 documentation for CXProvider:reportNewIncomingCall() https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxprovider/1930694-reportnewincomingcall

It says "An incoming call may be disallowed by the system if, for example, the caller handle is blocked, or the user has Do Not Disturb enabled."

How does a caller handle get blocked? Is blocking the handle something the app itself can do?

(Note if a phone number is registered with the CallKit extension as being blocked, then this does not prevent the Voip call screen being displayed when reportNewIncommingCall() is called, therefore I'm wondering how the caller handle gets blocked)